# RDP disconnection when the computer locks up

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I have a slight problem with a computer running on Windows 10. I have a remote session that I connect to via RDP, but for a few weeks now when the computer locks automatically after 10 minutes the RDP session is disconnected and I have to restart it and re-enter the credentials.

Normally if you lock the computer the session should not be interrupted.

Thank you for your answers.